# Using Video-JS with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, video, react-hooks, video.js

I'm trying to implement a video-js player with React using hooks. I'm able to initialise the player and everything is fine, I want to be able to update a state based on the current time of the video. The second `useEffect` runs once and doesn't want to continue re-rendering to update the state (`currentTime` stays at `0`), I'm sure the problem is simple and syntax based thanks!

```
export default function VideoPlayer ({ videoSrc }) {
  const videoPlayerRef = useRef() // Instead of ID
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(null)
  const videoJSOptions = {
    autoplay: 'muted',
    fluid: true,
    controls: true,
    userActions: { hotkeys: true },
    playbackRates: [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2]
  }
  // Initialise video player
  useEffect(() => {
    const player = videojs(videoPlayerRef.current, videoJSOptions, () => {
      player.src(videoSrc)
      console.log('Player Ready')
    })
    return () => {
      player.dispose()
      console.log('Player Disposed')
    }
  }, [])

  /* Testing video properties */
  useEffect(() => {
    const player = videojs(videoPlayerRef.current)
    setCurrentTime(player.currentTime())
  }, [currentTime])

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={videoPlayerRef} className='video-js' />
      <span>Current Time: {currentTime}</span>
      <GlobalStyle />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second useEffect only updates once because its dependencies array (basically when should the useEffect be run again) contains only currentTime, which is only set once (at the first run of the useEffect).

Let me know if this works for you.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/fast-dust-zvlbn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark